# Inherit AdminSite but can't get access to get_app_list in parent class (object has no attribute 'get_app_list')

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am customizing my admin page and having some trouble accessing `django.contrib.admin.AdminSite` methods. I am new to Django so take it easy if I my mistake is dumb

Here I try to extend `AdminSite` and override `index`in my `admin.py`

```
class MyAdmin(admin.AdminSite):
    @never_cache
    def index(self, request, extra_context=None):
        """
        Displays the main admin index page, which lists all of the installed
        apps that have been registered in this site.
        """
        app_list = super(MyAdmin, self).get_app_list(request)

        context = dict(
            self.each_context(request),
            title=self.index_title,
            app_list=app_list,
        )
        context.update(extra_context or {})

        request.current_app = super(MyAdmin, self).name

        return TemplateResponse(request, super(MyAdmin, self).index_template or
                                'admin/testing.html', context)

admin_site = MyAdmin(name='myadmin')
```

I have also tried to keep the

`self.get_app_list(request)`

but both gave me the same problem

> AttributeError at /myadmin/ 'super' object has no attribute
>   'get_app_list'

or

> AttributeError at /myadmin/ 'self' object has no attribute
>   'get_app_list'

I have already changed my `urls.py` and `settings.py` with the proper setup.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you got this idea, but looking at the source code, the `get_app_list` helper method was introduced in django 1.9.

Here are the links to the source code.

- [Django 1.8.5](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.5/django/contrib/admin/sites.py)
- [Django 1.9a1](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9a1/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L476)

And clearly, it looks like you are using django <= 1.8.5